# Reledmac: Display pstart number on outer margin

Tags: reledmac

Good morning everyone!

I'm pretty new to reledmac package and, although i read the manual several times i still can't figure out how to put the /pstart number on the outer margin of the page (like i can set line number in the inner margin).

Here's an example of what i mean:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do `reledmac`'s commands for paragraph numbering (section 5.2.5 in my copy of the manual) behave in your use case?

Comment: Of course I'm using \pstart in the \numberpstarttrue context and what I get is the classic bold number with the dot INSIDE the paragraph. So far, the closest command to what i'm searching for is \sidepstartnumtrue but this deletes the line numbering

Comment: Ok I figured it out by myself! The core element in this process is \thepstart, which recalls the number of the paragraph we are talking about. So, for example, if you need to put the number of paragraph on the margin, you can use \ledsidenote{\thepstart}. Of course it would be better to create a new command that automatizes the whole process.

Comment: A cool way to do it could be to create a newcommand like \newcommand{\myparagraph}{\pstart \ledsidenote{\thepstart}} and then all the paragraph should be written this way: \mypstart...\pend